# Identity element as product of transposition.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

My lecture notes indicates that the identity element of a symmetric group $S_{n}$ is

$\left (  \right )=\left ( 12 \right )\left ( 12 \right )$

Just to state:

> The identity element $b \in G$ where G is a group is the element b such that 
>   $\forall a,b \in G$ 
>   $a*b=b*a=a$

In a permutation group, however, we speak of elements as being permutations. 
And of course, by a certain theorem, any permutation of a finite set can be written as a cycle or as a product of disjoint cycles 
giving 
$\left ( a_{1}a_{2}\cdot \cdot \cdot a_{m} \right )\left ( b_{1}b_{2}\cdot \cdot \cdot b_{k} \right )\cdot \cdot \cdot $

In short, I am perhaps confused with how $\left (  \right )=\left ( 12 \right )\left ( 12 \right )$. In part because the notation looks strange.

Comment: Changes made to post due to typo.

Comment: The identity is also $(13)(31)$ or $(27)(72)$. What is strange about this? One transposition exchanges two entries; the other flips the entries back.

Comment: The notation $(12)(12)$ means the product of the transpositions.  The first application will swap $1$ and $2$, while the second application will put them back where they started.  In general a cycle $(a_1a_2\dots a_m)$ can be read as "$a_1$ gets sent to $a_2$ while $a_2$ gets sent to $a_3$,..., $a_{m-1}$ gets sent to $a_m$ and $a_m$ gets sent to $a_1$".  If you have a product of permutations, you apply them in succession.

Comment: Note: there are multiple ways to represent the same permutation.  What is true is that there will be a *unique way* (up to order) to represent the permutation as a product of disjoint cycles.  (To be more precise if we want to force it to be truly unique, we can have each cycle have its smallest element appearing at the end and the cycles arranged so that the smallest elements are in increasing order).  Also worth mentioning is that the empty product (product of no things) is still technically a product and is the identity.

Comment: @JMoravitz well say if the identity permutation is $\epsilon =\left ( 12 \right )\left ( 12 \right )$\ then wouldn't we be required to show\ $\epsilon * a= a * \epsilon = a \forall a, \epsilon \in G$?

Comment: To begin with, if you want to prove that $\epsilon$ is the identity, you need to prove $\epsilon * a=a*\epsilon=a$ for all $a\in G$.  $\epsilon$ is already fixed, we do not want to prove it is true for all possible values of $\epsilon$, just the one specific value of $\epsilon$ that we are interested in.  $\forall a,\epsilon\in G$ should only be $\forall a\in G$.  Next, are you being asked to prove the identity permutation satisfies this?  It should be clear from construction that the identity permutation has exactly this effect.  It is the permutation which does not change anything.

Answer (score 5):

Some reminders about permutations:

A permutation is by definition a bijective function from a set to itself.  The set of all permutations of $\{1,2,3,\dots,n\}$ (along with the operation of function composition) is referred to as the symmetric group $S_n$.

For example with $n=4$ we could have as an example of a permutation: $f=\{(1,2),(2,1),(3,3),(4,4)\}$, in other words $f(1)=2, f(2)=1, f(3)=3, f(4)=4$.

To simplify notation, we can refer to this in two-line format:  $f=\begin{pmatrix} 1&2&3&4\\f(1)&f(2)&f(3)&f(4)\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&4\\2&1&3&4\end{pmatrix}$

One can also prefer to write this in cyclic notation as well by "following the bouncing ball," keeping track of where one element gets mapped under repeated applications of the permutation until arriving back where it started.  In the above example, $f=(2~1)$

The identity permutation is the identity function $e(x)=x$.  In the context of $S_4$, that would be $e=\{(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4)\}$ or equivalently as $\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&4\\1&2&3&4\end{pmatrix}$ or equivalently as $(1)$ or $(~)$ depending on your preferred notation.

That the identity permutation is indeed the identity for the group $S_n$ is immediate from how it is defined since:

$(e\circ f)(x)=e(f(x))=f(x)$ for all $x$, so $e\circ f = f$.  Also $(f\circ e)(x)=f(e(x))=f(x)$ for all $x$, so $f\circ e = f$.

That the identity permutation can be written as the product of two equal transpositions follows from the fact that transpositions are self inverses.

Using the above example of $f=(2~1)$ again, we have:

$(f\circ f)(x)=f(f(x))=\begin{cases} f(f(1))&\text{if}~x=1\\ f(f(2))&\text{if}~x=2\\ f(f(x))&\text{for all other}~x\end{cases}=\begin{cases} f(2)&\text{if}~x=1\\ f(1)&\text{if}~x=2\\ f(x)&\text{for all other}~x\end{cases}=\begin{cases} 1&\text{if}~x=1\\ 2&\text{if}~x=2\\ x&\text{for all other}~x\end{cases}=x$ for all $x$.

Thus $f\circ f=(2~1)(2~1)=e$